# Changing the title of the MessageBox for DDX_Text()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

The message box which is displayed when validation has the title same as that of the project.
I searched MSDN and in google for changing the title of the message box for DDX_Text().

Below is the code snippet form

```
void CPower_Module::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_POWER_TXT_IGNITION_OFF_DELAY, delayOffWhenIgnitionIsOff);
}
```

When the user tries to delete the data in the text box, he will be shown a message Box as

[image]

with the application name as the title.
How do I change the title of the message box keeping the functionality same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally AfxMessageBox is called. This function always uses the application title as a title for the message box. The value is stored in CWinApp::m_pszAppname. It is just a LPCTSTR.

Just create a class like this.

```
class CChangeAppTitle
{
public:
  CChangeAppTitle(LPCTSTR pszNewTitle)
    : m_strTitle(pszNewTitle)
    , m_pszOldTitle(AfxGetApp()->m_pszAppTitle)
  {
    AfxGetApp()->m_pszAppTitle = m_strTitle;
  }
  ~CChangeAppTitle()
  {
    AfxGetApp()->m_pszAppTitle = m_pszOldTitle;
  }
private:
   CString m_strTitle;
  LPCTSTR m_pszOldTitle;
};
```

In DoDataExchange or before you call UpdateData just activate the class:

```
{ 
   CChangeAppTitle appTitle(_T("my app title");
   UpdateData();
...
```

Be aware that all message boxes that my be initiated by a timer, while this dialog is open, will show the new app title. Also a COM automation that is activated during this class is active will also return the changed app title.

Comment: Any idea on how to change the icon shown in the message box? It shows a warning icon, can I change it to error icon?

Comment: If you want more control over the DDX stuff write your own DDX routines. You find the code in the MFC and DDX routines aren't really compilcated.

Answer (score -1):

Just Set Your Caption in MessageBox Parameter.

```
CString v1_sMessageToDisplay;
v1_sMessageToDisplay.Format(_T("Saved Successfully to C:/IniGui/"));
MessageBox(v1_sMessageToDisplay, _T("Your Caption"), MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the question. He is not writing the code that calls `MessageBox`. The library is doing that internally.

Comment: but when i was searching for the solution i did not get any help. maybe someone also will search for the solution that is relevant to my code. then my code will be useful for him. i think you have understood. no need to downvote. I am trying to help other people.

Comment: A downvote means "This answer is not useful". This one isn't, for precisely the reason that I stated: it is not relevant to the question. If you want to answer questions about the `MessageBox` library function, find questions that actually ask about that library function. Don't answer unrelated questions with irrelevant answers. That doesn't help anyone. If you haven't already, please take the [tour].